# Is there a way to know if a Solidity method will revert?

Tags: solidity, web3js, calldata, revert-opcode, sendtransaction

I have some solidity methods in my contract, and when i make a send in web3.js i would like to know if there is a way to know if the functions are going to revert by using call.

Per-example , in Solidity i have a function that returns true, and i thought that if i used "call" in web3, i would get true if no revert and false or null if revert. But this is not the case, as when reverts, returns true anyway

Is there a way to know if it will revert?

Comment: It returns `true` because of a combined issue (still opened AFAIK) in both web3.js and Geth (which I assume you're using). Get rid of the revert-message inside the contract function, and it should work fine.

Comment: oh okay! I will remove the revert messages. Thank you!

Comment: NP, let me know if it works out for you.